# two array in Foreach

Tags: php

Good morning, folks.

I have a question here.

I have three select. Brings first product, quantity brings Second, Third brings value.
These are more select muntiplos as an array;

```
Ex:
$quantity = "1,2,3";
$value = "20.00,30.00,20.00";
```

Foreach had to do it.

```
    qty  value
$S ="1 * 20.00";
$S ="2 * 30.00";
$S ="1 * 20.00";
```

I am sending the page to have two to do the calculation.
More not getting to do two foreach with the data value and quantity.

Anyone know how I can sum this Vazer?

I would be very grateful.

```
EX:
  <select class="product" name=product[]" id="product[]">
             <option value="1"> Plan 1 </ option>
             <option value="2"> Plan 2 </ option>
  </ select>

  <select class="quantity" name=quantity[]" id="quantity[]">
             <option value="1"> 1 </ option>
             <option value="2"> 2 </ option>
  </ select>

  <select class="value" name=value[]" id="value[]">
             <option value="1"> 20:00 </ option>
             <option value="2"> 30.00 </ option>
  </ select>

Post
$quantity = $_POST["quantity"];
$value    = $_POST["value"];

$quantity = explode(',', $quantity_e);
$value    = explode(',', $value_e);

foreach ($quantity  as $q && $value as $v) { // ???

$v = $v * $q; // ????

}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking/trying to accomplish. Unless someone else does, please try to explain your problem again and I'll try my best to help.

Comment: i think last line should be `$S ="3 * 20.00";` and please paste the exactly desired output

Comment: +1 for "Anyone know how I can sum this Vazer?"

Comment: BTW it's conventional to write closing tags like `</select>`, not `< /select>`... and you forgot the opening quote for all your `name` parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all, you're not going to get any relevant information from your selects.  Your 3 input arrays will look like this

```
Array
(
    [name] => (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 1
    )

    [quantity] => (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 2
    )

    [value] => (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 2
    )
)
```

You are not passing anythign but 1's and 2's because the `value` attribute of all of your options is set to only 1's and 2's.

You can either remove the `value` attribute all together and it will pass the text in options, or you could set `value` to the actual value you want to pass.

Once you have the data in to format you originally specified, something like this would accomplish what I believe to be your goal.

```
// make arrays from your comma delimited strings
$quantity_array = explod(',',$quantity);
$value_array    = explode(',',$quanity);

// variable to store the total
$total = 0;

//iterate over them, summing them up
foreach ( $quantity_array as $i => $qty )  // $i is the index
{
    $item_total = $qty * $value_array[$i];  // the index should be the same for the values
    $total += $item_total;
}
```

Comment: I'm already going through. A multiple select, $ quantity = "1,2,3";
$ value = "20.00,30.00,20.00; Thus, I now want to create a foreach to get this value and compare two know how? use first, explode (',', $ quantity); More how do foreach or while receiving the two value?